# Django signals created value wrong return

Tags: django, django-signals

I am generating a reference number to an objects field. If the record is new, the signal will fill other fields before saving. If the record is not new, I also have an action for it. I will check for an objects specific field and see if it changed and do some other action.

Here is a snippet of the signal function:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=ProofOfPayment)
def pre_save_for_proof_of_payment(sender, instance, created=False, **kwargs):
    print('created', created)
    if created:
        upload_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
        reference_number = 'PAYMENT-' + upload_date
        instance.reference_number = reference_number
        received = PaymentStatus.objects.get(pk=1) # Received
        instance.payment_status = received
    else:
        obj = sender.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
        if not obj.payment_status == instance.payment_status:
            if instance.payment_status.name == 'Completed':
                instance.expiry_date = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
```

I am simulating the process in the admin. I create a new record. When I create the new object, I get an error because the variable `created` is set to `False`, doing the else function in the snippet.

```
obj = sender.objects.get(pk=instance.pk) 

ProofOfPayment matching query does not exist.
```

I am not sure why the `created` value is set to `False` even if the record is new.

When I don't place a default value in the function:

```
def pre_save_for_proof_of_payment(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
```

I get this error:

```
pre_save_for_proof_of_payment() missing 1 required positional argument: 'created'
```

When I set the default value to `created=True`, the signal does not get triggered when new record is made.

I am confused on how to use the `created` argument. What I knew is that Django will provide the boolean value based on if the record is new or not. But in this case, it is taking the default value once a new record is created.

What should be my default created boolean value such that I know when there is a new record as such in the `if created:` code block and when the record is not new such to trigger actions such as in the `else` codeblock.

My model goes like this.

```
class ProofOfPayment(models.Model):
    reference_number = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    payment_type = models.ForeignKey(
        PaymentType,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,)
    payment_status = models.ForeignKey(
        PaymentStatus,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,)
    receipt = models.FileField(
        upload_to='userproofofpayment',
        null=True,
        max_length=500)
    remarks = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    expiry_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.reference_number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have `created` argument in `pre_save` signal. You have to use `post_save` for such logic.

How can it say that's the object is created, when it's not saved yet?